# How to post Json by .Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i want to post two items into server by using ajax in java-script; based on server-side document the post url is like this

```
http://example.com/h/{first-item}/{second-item}
```

this is my java-script code:

```
  $('#add-order').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('#name');
    var drink = $('#drink');

    var order = ?? // my question is this part what should i add 

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://example.com/h/',
      data: order,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(data) {
       console.log("Data added!", data);
      }
    });
  });
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="input-group">
        <h4>Add a Coffee Order</h4>
        <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
        <p>name_space: <input type="text" id="drink"></p>
        <button id="add-order">Add!</button>
    </div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am a new in ajax, thanks for your help.

Comment: uhm. so, uh, what does json have to do with this? you provided code that sends form params to the server using the POST method, ignoring the requirement you have at the start. What does `name` and `drink` have to do with `first-item` and `second-item`?

Comment: actually name is may frist -item and drink is my second-item

Comment: Then pass them there rather than in data. Still isn't json.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert from object to string (json)

Comment: @AndreFeijo but... he doesn't watn to send that data as json, he wants it in the url. stringify wont' help with that.

Comment: @KevinB yes, you are right. Sorry, really hard to understand his question.

Comment: sorry for my code, i am new in programming, i think i have a problem to add a correct data to server

Comment: Think why everyone is confused is your script contains everything but JSON.  It's not magically created by JavaScript, you have to do something deliberate (like JSON.stringify()) to create it.  Are you understanding the role JSON is playing in this transaction?  You can go to a site like JSONLint and play with valid and invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `contentType` to `application/json` in your Ajax request.

i.e as following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/h/',
    data: order,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
     console.log("Data added!", data);
    }
  });
});
```

here is an example for creating and encoding a json object.

```
var myObj = { 
        "name": $('#name').val(),
        "drink": $('#drink').val()
}; 

var order = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Comment: this is wrong. You're now sending non-json data with a contentType that says it is json.

Comment: actually i am not sure about that part, i dont know what should i add there

Comment: Just added more details. Typing on the phone, so typesetting / formatting is a little messed up, sorry about that.

Comment: @KevinB you are right, didn't pay attention to the  order object. @Alex , here is an example for creating and encoding a json object.                                        `var myObj = { "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }; var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @KevinB

Answer (score -1):

Hard to really understand the post here, but it seems to me you simply forgot to mark the ajax requests contentType as json. See example below.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://example.com/h/',
      data: order,
      contentType: 'application/json'
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
         console.log("Data added!", data);
      }
});
```

Comment: Why did you add `dataType`? This will still not send the data as JSON btw.

Comment: still there is a problem, i think value of data is wrong: